# State Space Model in Controllable Canonical Form

Tags: control-systems

Mathematica by default puts state space model realizations in controllable companion form, as seen here:

```
tfsys = TransferFunctionModel[(b1 s^2 + b2 s + b3)/(s^3 + a1 s^2 + 
      a2 s + a3 ), s];
StateSpaceModel[tfsys]
```

Which outputs a block matrix like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -a_3 & -a_2 & -a_1 & 1 \\ b_3 & b_2 & b_1 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, I want it in [controllable canonical form](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Standard_Forms#Controllable_Canonical_Form), which should look like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
`StateSpaceModel` offers the `StateSpaceRealization` option but it only has `ControllableCompanion` and `ObservableCompanion`, neither of which is  what I want. Is there a simple way of getting the right state space form?

Answer (score 1):

```
StateSpaceModel[TransferFunctionModel[(b1 s^2 + b2 s + b3)/(s^3 + a1 s^2 + a2 s + a3), s]]
```

> [image]

And we can get the form you want by selecting the states in the desired order.

```
SystemsModelExtract[%, All, All, Reverse@Range@3]
```

> [image]

There doesn't seem to be a consensus on which of the above is the correct 'controllable canonical form'. Here are some sources ([link](https://www.engr.mun.ca/%7Emillan/Eng6825/canonicals.pdf), [link](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html#Controllable)) that call what is returned by Mathematica as the controllable canonical form.